# VC++ linker issue

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, strawberry-perl

I am using strawberry perl and GDI+ in a project. Everything is getting compiled properly and I am able to run perl scripts in the Debug mode. But when I am building a release version of my project and then running it, it gives following error

```
The procedure entry point GdipGetImageThumbnail could not be located in the
dynamic link library perl512.dll.
```

and application quits on saying OK. I am unable to understand why the system is searching for the API GdipGetImageThumbnail in perl512.dll when it is defined in gdiplus.lib.

Comment: Something wrong with the .lib for that DLL.  Use dumpbin.exe to take a look at it.  Don't keep the version a secret.

Comment: what is your linker command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using visual studio. Right click the projects in question. Go to properties and starting with the linker branch, check that all the fields are the same (where appropraite) for both Debug and Release configurations. If no success, check c/c++ and configuration properties. It would also be worth while to check the project dependencies / references. If the debug version is working, there is no reason for the release to not work.

It may also be wise to check that any classes referenced accross DLLs are defined as external. This may be useful : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z(v=vs.80).aspx#3

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

My senses tell me that you are misusing the `AFX_EXT_CLASS` macro.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/128199

> If you have extension DLLs that call or derive from classes in your
>   own extension DLLs, which then derive from the MFC classes, you must
>   use your own preprocessor symbol